# JavaScript Sudoku grid generation doesn't execute all the way

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

So I've been trying to generate a solved sudoku grid in JavaScript for a while now.
I now have a version that runs smoothly until a certain (always different) point.
I don't get any errors but at some point the function below just stops executing and I don't understand why.

Here is my source code:

```
//* HELPER FUNCTION FISHER-YATES SHUFFLE FOR ARRAYS
//* USE: shuffle(arr);
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex != 0) {
        // Pick a remaining element.
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;
        // And swap it with the current element.
        [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
            array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
    }
    return array;
}
//* HELPER FUNCTION get number in Range 0 and 8
function getRandomInRange() {
    return Math.random() * (8 - 0) + 0;
}
```

I implemented a fisher yates shuffle as it seems to be the same as the python array shuffle method that is used in python implementations of this problem.

```
let grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
let row;
let col;
let numberList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Above are all the global variables used.

```
//A function to check if the grid is full
function checkGrid() {
    for (let i = 0;i < 9;i++) {
        for (let j = 0;j < 9;j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] === 0) {
                //The grid is not full
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    //The grid is complete
    return true
}
```

The function above checks, if there is still a 0 left in the sudoku grid

Below is the function that fills the grid value by value. This is the function that stops executing at some point. Can this be a problem with JavaScript itself because of the recursion, or is it a mistake on my behalf?

```
function fillGrid() {
    //let counter;
    for (let i = 0;i < 81;i++) {
        row = Math.floor(i / 9);
        col = i % 9;
        if (grid[row][col] === 0) {
            //console.log(row + "/" + col);
            shuffle(numberList);
            numberList.forEach(v => {
                //Check that this value has not already been used on this row
                if (!grid[row].includes(v)) {
                    //Check that this value has not already been used on this column
                    if (grid[0][col] !== v &&
                        grid[1][col] !== v &&
                        grid[2][col] !== v &&
                        grid[3][col] !== v &&
                        grid[4][col] !== v &&
                        grid[5][col] !== v &&
                        grid[6][col] !== v &&
                        grid[7][col] !== v &&
                        grid[8][col] !== v
                    ) {
                        //Identify which of the 9 squares we are working on
                        let square = [];

                        if (row < 3) {
                            if (col < 3) {
                                for (let x = 0;x < 3;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(0, 3));
                                }
                            }
                            else if (col < 6) {
                                for (let x = 0;x < 3;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(3, 6));
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                for (let x = 0;x < 3;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(6));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (row < 6) {
                            if (col < 3) {
                                for (let x = 3;x < 6;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(0, 3));
                                }
                            }
                            else if (col < 6) {
                                for (let x = 3;x < 6;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(3, 6));
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                for (let x = 3;x < 6;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(6));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (col < 3) {
                                for (let x = 6;x < 9;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(0, 3));
                                }
                            }
                            else if (col < 6) {
                                for (let x = 6;x < 9;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(3, 6));
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                for (let x = 6;x < 9;x++) {
                                    square.push(grid[x].slice(6));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //Check that this value has not already been used on this 3x3 square
                        if (!square[0].includes(v) &&
                            !square[1].includes(v) &&
                            !square[2].includes(v)
                        ) {
                            grid[row][col] = v;
                            if (checkGrid()) {
                                return true
                            } else {
                                if (fillGrid()) {
                                    return true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            break
        }
    }
    grid[row][col] = 0;
}

//generate a fully solved grid
fillGrid();
grid.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

No matter, if I run it in node or chrome, with or without debugging tools, I never achieve a fully filled grid.
Example results:

```
(9) [9, 4, 7, 5, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2]
(9) [3, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1, 7, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or

```
(9) [6, 1, 3, 9, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2]
(9) [4, 8, 9, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1]
(9) [7, 2, 5, 3, 1, 8, 6, 9, 4]
(9) [3, 7, 2, 5, 9, 6, 8, 1, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(9) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You can't just randomly assign numbers and assume it will be a correct Sudoku grid.  Look at your second example, trying to fill the last cell in the fourth row.  `4` has already been used in the column, and the remaining numbers have all been used in the row.  You will need to do some back-tracking.

Comment: @Scott You are right! Thanks for bringing that to my attention. But that's weird. I have a python implementation of this exact functionality here: https://trinket.io/python/8b8653f0b9

The function works successfully every time.  I tried to translate that 1to1 to JS but apparently I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Oh, now it looks like the backtracking is there, resetting with `grid[row][col] = 0;`.  I would replace the `forEach` with `for (let v of numberList) {`,  and look very closely at the placement of your `break` statement.  I can't guarantee that will fix it, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was misplaced in the translation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[3, 8, 4, 1, 6,2, 9, 5, 7],
[6, 5, 2, 9, 7,3, 4, 8, 1],
[7, 9, 1, 4, 5,8, 6, 3, 2],
[4, 6, 3, 5, 9,7, 8, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I got the error in line 4. Your script has to set a 2 but can't set it because it already exists in these columns. You have to write a function that handles the event of having a conflict.